# Wiremock - Mocking a reactive backend

Tags: wiremock, reactor

Is it possible to use Wiremock to mock a reactive backend. What I want to do is make Wiremock return chunked responses but each chunk should be a valid json string (something that mimics a reactor Flux type response).

The scenario is something like this, I have a backend sending a stream of json objects that I can consume. Each json string can be marshalled into a POJO without the need to keep track of the state (the chunk that came before). Each chunk that comes over the wire can have different lengths.

Any ideas on how I can mock such a backend?

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all, of API mocking, stubbing, faking, replacing libraries (there a wide variety of names but it is fair to refer to these as API stubbing) such as [wiremock](/questions/tagged/wiremock) do not support response payload chunking.

You are then left with two options:

- A custom hand-made implementation, where you provide chunking based on the used library and its semantics
- A simple test-scoped `Controller` stereotype that returns a reactive (`Flux`) for your endpoint. Then you let the underlying framework (*Spring WebFlux* for example) handle the response streaming for you (the cleanest option in my opinion)

That being said, you should be good to go with a mock API where you return an iterable type which will get mapped automatically by the client to its reactive counterpart, `Flux`, when called. The mapping and request / response handling is low level detail, and its the responsibility of the underlying framework to map your input and output accordingly and you should not bother with how the endpoint is implemented as your client should be working in all cases the same way. It is the responsibility of the framework to interoperability after all and not the responsibility of an application developer.